# Error Code: 1118. Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format,

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 600 fields in which datatype of all the 600 fields is  'TEXT'.

Now when we are trying to insert some data to this table it is showing the below error

> Error Code: 1118. Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline

My configuration file contains the following parameters:

```
innodb_strict_mode=OFF
innodb_log_file_size = 2G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 512M
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
max_allowed_packet = 1G
```

But still, couldn't insert the data. I there any way we can resolve this?

Comment: This may make useful reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 12):

If InnoDB strict mode (10.5.9-MariaDB) is enabled this error can show.

Check enabled or not

```
SHOW  variables LIKE '%strict%';
```

If enable then you can disable.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_strict_mode=OFF;
```

For more detail information read [here>>](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-row-size-too-large-errors-with-innodb/)

Comment: Hi @Nanhe Kumar, do you know why my innodb_strict_mode can still be ON after "SET GLOBAL..."? I run "SHOW  variables LIKE '%strict%';" once before SET and once after SET, and both times it is ON

Comment: @GrumpyCivet : If you are using phpmyadmin then issue may occour clear or phpmyadmin cookies and login again

Answer (score 4):

Try to add following options to your configuration file:

1. To activate new file format: `innodb_file_format = Barracuda`
2. To store each table in own file: `innodb_file_per_table=1`
3. To prevent surprises: `innodb_strict_mode=ON`

To store long variable-length column values use *dynamic* or *compressed* row format for large tables. For example,  use

```
ALTER TABLE LargeTable ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-row-size-too-large-errors-with-innodb/) worked for me.
For those using MariaDB 10.2 and later, the DYNAMIC row format is the default row format therefore increase the length of VARCHAR in the affected table

E.g

> col1 varchar(256) NOT NULL,

The 256 byte limit means that a VARCHAR column will only be stored on overflow pages if it is at least as large as a varchar(256):

You can learn more [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/troubleshooting-row-size-too-large-errors-with-innodb/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply in my.ini file, add below line.It worked for me.

innodb_strict_mode = 0